# How do I keep Richtext box from expanding?

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a RichTextBox inside my application, and as I add text to it, the text box expands vertically.  I want it to dynamically size if the application is stretched, but not expand if text is added to it.

Here is my ALL of my xaml code:

```
<Grid Background="#FF1F1F1F">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5"  Margin="10,10,10,0" BorderBrush="#FF878383" CornerRadius="10">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF323232" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <Grid UseLayoutRounding="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="Server: " VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="0" Margin="3" Foreground="White" />
                    <Label x:Name="ServerIDLabel" Content="" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="0" Margin="3" Foreground="White" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="Port: " VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="0" Margin="3" Foreground="White" />
                    <Label Name="txtPort" Content="10037" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3" Foreground="White" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="IP:" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="0" Margin="3" Foreground="White" />
                    <Label Name="IPAddress" Content="255.255.255.255" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3" Foreground="White" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="Version:" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="0" Margin="3" Foreground="White" />
                    <Label Name="lblVersionNumber" Content="3.0.0.0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3" Foreground="White" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

            <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5" BorderBrush="#FF878383" CornerRadius="10">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ManagerNoticeLabel" Text="Notifications:" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" />
                            <Button Margin="25,0" x:Name="ClearManagerNotifications" Content="Clear" Click="ClearManagerNotifications_Click" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <DockPanel >
                            <RichTextBox Name="ManagerNotice" Background="#FF343434" Foreground="#FFDEDEDE" >
                                <RichTextBox.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </RichTextBox.Resources>
                            </RichTextBox>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
            </Border>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="2" >
                <Button Name="btnStartServer" Content="Start" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Click="btnStartServer_Click"></Button>
                <Button Name="btnStopServer" Content="Stop" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Click="btnStopServer_Click" IsEnabled="False" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <my:VersionDisplayControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="versionDisplayControl" Margin="10,10,10,0" />

    <my:AgentActionsControl Grid.Row="2" x:Name="agentActionsControl" Margin="10,10,10,0" />

    <Border Grid.Row="3" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5"  Margin="10" BorderBrush="#FF878383" CornerRadius="10">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF323232" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="28"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,5,0" x:Name="Summary_Agents">
                        <Label x:Name="AgentsLabel"  Content="Agents:" Foreground="Lime" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="13" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" />
                        <Label Content="0" x:Name="lblAgentCount" Foreground="Lime" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="13" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" />
                        <Label x:Name="OfLabel"  Content="of" Foreground="Lime" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="13" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" />
                        <Label Content="0" x:Name="lblMaxAgentCount" Foreground="Lime" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="13" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0" x:Name="Summary_HardwareInventory" >
                        <Label x:Name="HdInvLabel"  Content="Hard Inv" Foreground="Lime" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="13" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" />
                        <Label Content="0" x:Name="lblHdInvCount" Foreground="Lime" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="13" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" />
                        <Label x:Name="OfHdInvLabel"  Content="of" Foreground="Lime" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="13" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" />
                        <Label Content="0" x:Name="lblHdInvCountMax" Foreground="Lime" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="13" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0" x:Name="Summary_SoftwareInventory" >
                        <Label x:Name="SfInvLabel"  Content="Soft Inv" Foreground="Lime" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="13" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" />
                        <Label Content="0" x:Name="lblSfInvCount" Foreground="Lime" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="13" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" />
                        <Label x:Name="OfSfInvLabel"  Content="of" Foreground="Lime" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="13" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" />
                        <Label Content="0" x:Name="lblSfInvCountMax" Foreground="Lime" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="13" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="3" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0" x:Name="Summary_E2P">
                        <Label x:Name="E2InvLabel"  Content="E2P" Foreground="Lime" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="13" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" />
                        <Label Content="0" x:Name="lblE2InvCount" Foreground="Lime" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="13" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" />
                        <Label x:Name="OfE2InvLabel"  Content="of" Foreground="Lime" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="13" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" />
                        <Label Content="0" x:Name="lblE2InvCountMax" Foreground="Lime" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="13" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" />
                    </StackPanel>

                </Grid>


                <!-- a grid -->
                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True" >
                        <StackPanel Name="spAgents" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>

            </Grid>


        </Grid>
    </Border>

</Grid>
```

Thanks

I changed it to a DockPanel and it still sizes up when adding text ( see above )

Here is another project where it does NOT grow with additional text added:

```
<Border Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,5,0,5">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" >
            <RichTextBox Name="txtMessageHistory" Margin="5" Background="#FF343434" Foreground="#FFDEDEDE" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <RichTextBox.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                    </Style>
                </RichTextBox.Resources>
            </RichTextBox>
        </DockPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBox x:Name="ChatTextBox" Background="#FFDEDEDE" Foreground="Black" Margin="5,5,5,5" />
            <StackPanel   Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="SendMsg" Content="Send msg " Click="btnSendMessage_Click" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                <Button x:Name="ClearMessages" Content="Clear messages" Click="ClearMessages_Click"  Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                <Button x:Name="SendMsg_Ping" Content="Send Ping" Click="SendMsg_Ping_Click" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                <Button x:Name="SendMsg_E2PRequest" Content="Send E2P Request" Click="SendMsg_E2PRequest_Click" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                <Button x:Name="SendMsg_MARequest" Content="Send Mon App Request" Click="SendMsg_MARequest_Click"  Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                <Button x:Name="SendMsg_PluginStatusRequest" Content="Send Plugin stat Request" Click="SendMsg_PluginStatusRequest_Click" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Another try:

Removed Grid and Dockpanel - still grows in size:

```
            <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5" BorderBrush="#FF878383" CornerRadius="10">
                <Grid>
                    <RichTextBox Name="ManagerNotice" Background="#FF343434" Foreground="#FFDEDEDE" >
                        <RichTextBox.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                            </Style>
                        </RichTextBox.Resources>
                    </RichTextBox>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
```

Attempt (last and this is working)

When I explicitly set the height to some number, it behaves

```
                    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" >
                        <RichTextBox Height="100" Name="ManagerNotice" Margin="5" Background="#FF343434" Foreground="#FFDEDEDE" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                            <RichTextBox.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                                </Style>
                            </RichTextBox.Resources>
                        </RichTextBox>
                    </DockPanel>
```

Comment: Try taking it out of the ScrollViewer. It already knows how to scroll. I think it should just stretch to the Grid then.

Comment: Ya agree with Ed, since you're giving it infinite space to grow dude, however, it's still in a `*` height Row, so it still will grow with whatever space it can, if you want to keep it at the height it's initially rendered at just lock that value in via binding, something like <RichTextBox MaxHeight="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ..../>

Comment: Nah you don't need DockPanel, or that Grid, or anything, just put your Grid.Row definition directly on the RichTextBox, it already has a parent, which is the Grid it's sitting in.

Comment: All you want, is after the measure/arrange pass when it renders, have that be the initial set maxheight size right? Or am I missing something.

Comment: I am not messing around with any measuring / arranging... I am using the Visual Studio editor... setting up the controls so they are in a location I want them, then I run the application and add text to the rich text edit box... which grows the entire application when it gets full and adds a new line - so to answer your question - no, I want it the size I set in visual studio.  ( just like the other application I xaml code I posted up )

Comment: The RichText box is in a grid, which is parented in a Width="Auto" column of a parent grid. That parent Grid is in Border which is in Row 0 (Height="Auto") of the outermost Grid. So effectively -- unless I'm even more confused than I usually am with Grid layouts -- there's nothing constraining the height. I would try setting the outermost Row 0 `Height="*"`. The last row of that outermost grid has `Height="*"` too, but that's OK: The two of them will just evenly divide up what's left after the Auto columns eat what they need.

Comment: If you want it to grow *up to* a given size, and no further, that's harder. But MaxHeight="300" or something on the RichTextBox will limit its growth, though not proportionally to the size of the window. Worse comes to worst, you could always give in and give the Window a readonly DepedencyProperty that returns some percentage of its ActualHeight, and bind that to RichTextBox.MaxHeight. Or write a converter.

Comment: I hate / love xaml coding... thanks Ed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer, after multiple comments and great feedback:

```
                <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" >
                    <RichTextBox Height="100" Name="ManagerNotice" Margin="5" Background="#FF343434" Foreground="#FFDEDEDE" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                        <RichTextBox.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                            </Style>
                        </RichTextBox.Resources>
                    </RichTextBox>
                </DockPanel>
```